# merge tables in two databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have at present two different databases, and i would like to copy or merge all columns from table A into table B. I am using the following commands

```
USE B;
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A.col1;
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A.col2;
etc
```

What I would like to achieve is

For example, database A contains tables (A_1, A_2); database B contains tables (B_1, B_2);
and the newly created B should be (A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2)

Thanks Gosh it doesn't work at all;

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get you.

Do you want to merge columns of a table

or merge tables of a database?

To merge columns of 2 tables into 1 table

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2
into newtable 
from table1,table2
```

---

but to merge all tables in a database, that is much simpler.
Just create the database and import tables from both DBs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link server to mysql in sql-server and use openquery to access the tables from mysql database.

**How to create link server of MySql in SqlServer**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkServerName', 
@srvproduct=N'anything',
 @provider=N'MSDASQL',
  @datasrc=N'DBNAME', 
  @provstr=N'gr_uid=userid; gr_pwd=password',
   @catalog=N'dbase'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LinkServerName',
@useself=N'false',
@locallogin=null,
@rmtuser=userid,
@rmtpassword=password
```

**How to access table data from mySql through LinkServer.**

```
Select *  FROM OPENQUERY([LinkServerName],'SELECT * FROM MySqlTableName')
```

Comment: What do you mean by command line. Are you try to access mysql tables and trying to update sql server. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE B;
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A.col1;
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A.col2;
etc
```

That code is not correct.

That is simple example for sql server:

```
USE [DATABASE];
INSERT INTO [DESTINATION TABLE] SELECT * FROM [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[SOURCE TABLE]
```

or

```
SELECT * INTO [NEW TABLE] FROM [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[SOURCE TABLE]
```

and I suggest to explicit write columns in tables.